# can't select the YES option

Tags: forms, watir, watir-webdriver

How do i make Watir select a specific radio button? I have 4 radio buttons, and i want it to select the second one:

```
//this will select the first option
ie.radio(:name, "radio1").set()
```

I can even set the second option for another radio button doing the following (**for a different radio button**):

```
ie.radio(:value => '1').set
```

however, i have the following radio button:

```
<input type=radio   name='myRadio' id='myRadio-0' value='0' tabindex=8 ><span class=smalll>0. No</span>
<input type=radio   name='myRadio' id='myRadio-1' value='1' tabindex=8 ><span 
class=smalll>1. Yes</span>
```

I want to select the the "YES" option here, but no matter what i try, i can't. How do i get around this? I've tried the following:

```
ie.radio(:value => '1').set
ie.radio(:name, "myRadio-1").set
ie.radio(:name, "myRadio").set
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you've used name twice, even though "myRadio-1" is the id of the element, not the name.  If that was a typo just in this post and not in your actual code, I would assume that one of the two radio buttons not provided (of the four total) has a conflicting name/id, etc.

For HTML:

```
<input type=radio   name='myRadio' id='myRadio-1' value='1' tabindex=8 >
```

I would use:

```
@browser.radio(:id => "myRadio-1").set
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically radio buttons are in a group. In the examples I've seen, people set the one radio out of the group rather than focus on a radio button.